# Setting data for Google Chart inside my JQuery Ajax Json parsing function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, charts

I have the following jquery function:

```
function doReport(query) {
   var rowArray = [];
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxxxxxx' + query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var sales = $('#salesDiv');
            sales.html('');
            for (res in data['sales']) {
                sales.append('<div>' + data['sales'][res]['contractName'] + ' : $' + data['sales'][res]['salesAmount'] + '</br></div><br />');
                rowArray.push([data['sales'][res]['contractName'],data['sales'][res]['salesAmount']]);
                    alert("this works! "+rowArray[0]);
            }
        }
    });
    alert("this doesnt work "+rowArray[0]);
    drawChart(rowArray);
```

My question is in my first alert (this works!) i can see the value of rowArray.
However in the second alert(this doesnt work), the values comes back as undefined.

What am i doing wrong?  please help!
I want to pass the values into my drawChart function and get my nice google pie chart to appear!

Answer (score 0):

Basically `$.ajax` works asynchronously. So your code may not always work.

Call `drawChart` inside the callback.

```
function doReport(query) {
   var rowArray = [];
   $.ajax({
        url: 'http://xxxxxxx' + query,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var sales = $('#salesDiv');
            sales.html('');
            for (res in data['sales']) {
                sales.append('<div>' + data['sales'][res]['contractName'] + ' : $' + data['sales'][res]['salesAmount'] + '</br></div><br />');
                rowArray.push([data['sales'][res]['contractName'],data['sales'][res]['salesAmount']]);
                    alert("this works! "+rowArray[0]);
            }
            drawChart(rowArray);
        }
    });
    alert("this doesnt work "+rowArray[0]);
    //drawChart(rowArray); - moved
```

---

**EDITED**

FYI, from jQuery API document (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> The first letter in Ajax stands for **"asynchronous,"** meaning that *the
>   operation occurs in parallel and the order of completion **is not
>   guaranteed***. The async option to $.ajax() defaults to true, indicating
>   that code execution can continue after the request is made. ***Setting
>   this option to false*** (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous)
>   **is strongly discouraged**, as it can cause the browser to become
>   unresponsive.